# Tableau, uphill task to replace datasource

Tags: excel, tableau-api

In general, when I wish to replace one EXCEL worksheet with another in tableau, the changes don't take effect.

Usually I reopen the new EXCEL file, reopen Tableau, sometimes even renaming the EXCEL file, and even then, it just doesn't work.

I thought something simple as replacing Tableau datasource would be seamless, why does it continue to use old, outdated datasource.

Or is there a step I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this in Tableau in 2 steps.
The first is the the data connection which you already done. 
The 2nd if your base data has changed then you have to extract the data.
select the data window -> extract data -> extract
The reason to this is that the first part usually involves query (not in your case) which defines your data set. the 2nd is to refresh whenever your row data has been change. you can set this to run automatically as well.